# Difference between `call inherit-product` and `include` in AOSP makefiles?

Tags: gnu-make, android-source

I'm looking through the Android Open Source Project makefiles, and I'm seeing what appears to be two different ways of including another makefile.  For example, `master/build/target/product/aosp_arm64.mk` has these lines:

```
PRODUCT_COPY_FILES += frameworks/native/data/etc/android.hardware.ethernet.xml:system/etc/permissions/android.hardware.ethernet.xml

$(call inherit-product, $(SRC_TARGET_DIR)/product/core_64_bit.mk)
$(call inherit-product, $(SRC_TARGET_DIR)/product/aosp_base_telephony.mk)
$(call inherit-product, $(SRC_TARGET_DIR)/board/generic_arm64/device.mk)

include $(SRC_TARGET_DIR)/product/emulator.mk

PRODUCT_NAME := aosp_arm64
PRODUCT_DEVICE := generic_arm64
PRODUCT_BRAND := Android
PRODUCT_MODEL := AOSP on ARM arm64 Emulator
```

What is the difference(s) between the `$(call inherit-product ...)` line and the `include ...` line?

Comment: `$(call inherit-product, $(SRC_TARGET_DIR)/product/core_64_bit.mk)` is
not a way of inclduing another makefile. It's a [call to the user-defined
make-function](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Call-Function.html)
`inherit-product` with the argument `$(SRC_TARGET_DIR)/product/core_64_bit.mk`.
To know that that function does you'll have to search for its definition.

Answer (score 13):

`include` just includes the file. `inherit-product` does that and three more things accordig to file in link below:

1. Inherits all of the variables from $1.
2. Records the inheritance in the .INHERITS_FROM variable
3. Records that we've visited this node, in ALL_PRODUCTS

See line 113 in this file for details [core/product.mk](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/+/157a5e1/core/product.mk)

Comment: Maybe just a link directly to the mentioned line: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/+/157a5e1/core/product.mk#113

Answer (score 5):

Let's say you have `PRODUCT_VAR := a` in A.mk, `PRODUCT_VAR := b` in B.mk.

If you include B.mk in A.mk, you will get `PRODUCT_VAR := b` at last.

But if you `inherit-product` B.mk in A.mk, you will get `PRODUCT_VAR := a b`.

And `inherit-product` makes sure that you won't include a makefile twice because it `Records that we've visited this node, in ALL_PRODUCTS`.